# clickhouse modify arrays inside arry

Tags: sql, arrays, json, clickhouse, redash

Given the following query:

```
SELECT
    arrayZip(Groups.Names, Groups.Scores) AS ZipGroups,
    arrayZip(Symbols.Names, Symbols.Scores) AS ZipSymbols
FROM rspamd
WHERE (IsBayes = 'spam') AND ((Action = 'no action') OR (Action = 'greylist')) AND (Score <= 6.3) AND notEmpty(Symbols.Names) AND ((Date >= (now() - toIntervalHour(72))) AND (Date <= now()))
ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 1
```

This returns something like:

```
Row 1:
──────
ZipGroups:  [('MX',0.5),('policies',-0.9),('reputation',1.5636996),('mime_types',-0.1),('headers',0.5),('dkim',-0.2),('arc',0),('dmarc',-1),('Message ID',0),('url',1),('statistics',3.796762),('neural',-1),('spf',-0.2)]
ZipSymbols: [('ARC_NA',0),('BAYES_SPAM',3.796762),('R_DKIM_ALLOW',-0.2),('MX_INVALID',0.5),('FROM_HAS_DN',0),('MV_CASE',0.5),('TO_MATCH_ENVRCPT_ALL',0),('MIME_GOOD',-0.1),('R_SPF_ALLOW',-0.2),('URI_COUNT_ODD',1),('RCPT_COUNT_ONE',0),('MID_RHS_MATCH_FROMTLD',0),('TO_DN_ALL',0),('DKIM_TRACE',0),('DMARC_POLICY_ALLOW',-1),('NEURAL_HAM_SHORT',-1),('IP_REPUTATION_SPAM',1.5636996),('RCVD_COUNT_ZERO',0),('FROM_EQ_ENVFROM',0),('MIME_TRACE',0),('ASN',0)]
```

I find the result very unreadable and would like to convert it. I use "redash". I could use JSON as display option. It would be nicer to have the result like:

```
["key1": value1, "key2": value2, ...]
```

[Update 2021-02-17 11:00 CET]

The source of values from the arrays are:

Symbols.Names and Symbols.Scores. They match 1:1. So each SQL record has these two fields. And I want a combined output in JSON format.

Here is one example record from SQL:

```
Groups.Names:   ['statistics','policies','reputation','mime_types','headers','local','arc','Message ID','body','neural']
Groups.Scores:  [-2.2,0,-0.7413712,-2.2,2.1666667,0,0,0,0,-1]
Symbols.Names:  ['ARC_NA','RCVD_VIA_SMTP_AUTH','TO_DOM_EQ_FROM_DOM','BAYES_HAM','FROM_HAS_DN','LOCAL_META_LEARN_HAM_1','MV_CASE','TO_MATCH_ENVRCPT_ALL','MIME_GOOD','PREVIOUSLY_DELIVERED','HAS_ATTACHMENT','RCPT_COUNT_ONE','GENERIC_REPUTATION','TO_DN_ALL','NEURAL_HAM_SHORT','HAS_X_PRIO_THREE','RCVD_COUNT_ONE','SIGNED_PGP','POLICY_SUBMISSION','MIME_TRACE','R_MIXED_CHARSET','ASN','RCVD_TLS_ALL','MID_RHS_MATCH_FROM','FROM_EQ_ENVFROM']
Symbols.Scores: [0,0,0,-2.2,0,0,0.5,0,-0.2,0,0,0,-0.7413712,0,-1,0,0,-2,0,0,1.6666666,0,0,0,0]
```

For the given example above, I would love to have a result for Symbols like this:

```
{
  "ARC_NA": 0,
  "BAYES_SPAM": 3.796762,
  "R_DKIM_ALLOW": -0.2,
  "MX_INVALID": 0.5,
  "FROM_HAS_DN": 0,
  "MV_CASE": 0.5,
  "TO_MATCH_ENVRCPT_ALL": 0,
  "MIME_GOOD": -0.1,
  "R_SPF_ALLOW": -0.2,
  "URI_COUNT_ODD": 1,
  "RCPT_COUNT_ONE": 0,
  "MID_RHS_MATCH_FROMTLD": 0,
  "TO_DN_ALL": 0,
  "DKIM_TRACE": 0,
  "DMARC_POLICY_ALLOW": -1,
  "NEURAL_HAM_SHORT": -1,
  "IP_REPUTATION_SPAM": 1.5636996,
  "RCVD_COUNT_ZERO": 0,
  "FROM_EQ_ENVFROM": 0,
  "MIME_TRACE": 0,
  "ASN": 0
}
```

[/Update]

Is it somehow possible to convert the query to get a result like shown?

Comment: could you provide the expected JSON for your input (*[('MX',0.5),('policies',-0.9),..*)?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT formatRow('JSONEachRow', x, y) AS z
FROM
(
    SELECT
        number AS x,
        number / 3 AS y
    FROM numbers(3)
)

Query id: 1413bd9f-bd32-48fc-b1e0-ac4eadd41f11

┌─z────────────────────────────────┐
│ {"x":"0","y":0}
                  │
│ {"x":"1","y":0.3333333333333333}
 │
│ {"x":"2","y":0.6666666666666666}
 │
└──────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you show me on my examples above, how you think that could work?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    x,
    concat('{', arrayStringConcat(arrayMap((x, y) -> concat('"', x, '": ', toString(y)), `Symbols.Names`, `Symbols.Scores`), ', '), '}') AS j
FROM
(
    SELECT
        1 AS x,
        ['ARC_NA', 'RCVD_VIA_SMTP_AUTH', 'TO_DOM_EQ_FROM_DOM'] AS `Symbols.Names`,
        [-2.2, 2, 0] AS `Symbols.Scores`
)

Query id: 6a852799-35ee-44ed-a58e-331eaf5917a2

┌─x─┬─j──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ 1 │ {"ARC_NA": -2.2, "RCVD_VIA_SMTP_AUTH": 2, "TO_DOM_EQ_FROM_DOM": 0} │
└───┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```